# Handling Daylight Saving Time

Tags: python-3.x, time, timezone

In Python 3.x, I want to capture current time along with its timezone and then convert it into Unix timestamp and sent to a server.

I have tried various libraries like [pytz](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pytz), [arrow](https://pypi.org/search/?q=arrow), [moment](https://pypi.org/search/?q=moment), [pendulum](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pendulum), but I am not sure how to deal with daylight saving time (DST). Currently, I am using `time.tzname` to get timezone information but it specifically showing India in DST.  In reality India never follows DST.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also add some minimal code snippet.

Comment: Unix timestamps are always UTC based. Thus, if you just want the current time as a Unix timestamp, just get the current UTC time directly. No need to involve time zones or DST.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755394/634824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me in resolving the issue using **time.tzname**

```
    if time.tzname[1] is None or time.tzname[0] == time.tzname[1]:
        timezone = time.localtime().tm_zone
            # no DST
            timezone = time.tzname[0]
        else:

            # we're in DST
            timezone = time.tzname[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The library `pytz` should work pretty well. You need to use the function `dst()` from that library to check if a timezone is under daylight savings influence.

https://medium.com/@nqbao/python-timezone-and-daylight-savings-e511a0093d0

From the link above:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pst = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
>>> pst.localize(datetime(2017, 10, 1)).dst()
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
>>> pst.localize(datetime(2017, 12, 1)).dst()
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Understanding offset naive and offset aware date times will make your life much easier.

Comment: @Csaba_Nemeth Thanks for your input. Please edit your answer and quote the essential parts from the website you cited. It might also help, if you add a minimal working code snippet.