# Convert datetime format to unix timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, format, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to convert datetime format to unix timestamp. How can I do this. Could anyone help me ?

```
import datetime
time_of_day = datetime.datetime.now()
replaced_time = time_of_day.replace(hour=0, minute=0)
```

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542723/change-datetime-to-unix-time-stamp-in-python) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801727/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-and-convert-it-back-in-python) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python/8778548#8778548)?