# In Python, how can I turn this format into a unix timestamp?

Tags: python, date

```
Mon Jul 09 09:20:28 +0000 2012
```

If I have a format like that as a STRING, how can I turn it into a unix timestamp?

Note: I'm getting this format from Twitter's API:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitter

Comment: You'll need to parse it: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: see this http://devpython.com/2011/08/11/convert-utc-date-string-to-unix-timestamp/

Comment: @Blender: The OP's format seems to be tricky. For the `+0000` he needs `%z` but that results in `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'`

Comment: Why can't API creators just stick with ISO 8601? >.<

Comment: @ThiefMaster, it looks like it works using Python3.2 (at least Portable Python). Apparently it depends on your underlying implementation of C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-to-datetime-object-in-python

Answer (score 9):

The best option is using `dateutil.parser.parse()` which gives you a `datetime` object with proper timezone information:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dt = dateutil.parser.parse('Mon Jul 09 09:20:28 +0200 2012')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 9, 9, 20, 28, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

Now you just need to convert it to a UNIX timestamp:

```
>>> import time
>>> int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
1341822028
```

---

The format you have can also be easily parsed using [`email.utils.parsedate_tz`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_tz):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import email.utils
>>> parts = email.utils.parsedate_tz('Mon Jul 09 09:20:28 +0200 2012')
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(*parts[:6]) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=parts[-1])
>>> str(dt)
'2012-07-09 07:20:28'
```

This is actually how `email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime` in Python 3.3 is implemented (if you want to copy&paste this into your project, replace `__parsedate_tz` with `parsedate_tz` from `email.utils`):

```
def parsedate_to_datetime(data):
    if not data:
        return None
    *dtuple, tz = __parsedate_tz(data)
    if tz is None:
        return datetime.datetime(*dtuple[:6])
    return datetime.datetime(*dtuple[:6],
            tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=tz)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the timezone is known to be always +0000, you can use:

```
time.strptime('Mon Jul 09 09:20:28 +0000 2012', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
```

This returns a datetime structure. If you need unix seconds since epoch, run through time.mktime(), like this:

```
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime('Mon Jul 09 09:20:28 +0000 2012', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
1341818428.0
```

or time.gmtime() if indeed the timezone is always UTC.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.strptime()`

**Reference**: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

Comment: So, why not include some example code that actually parses the format he used without an error?

Comment: then you need to convert to unix timestamp... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp
@thiefmaster ... I think that hope's answer is sufficient to get him where he wants to be as well as allowing him to figure it out for other formats

Comment: @JoranBeasley: See my comment on the question. His format is apparently not *that* trivial to parse.

Comment: its real easy if he removes the offset(with regex or splits or replace or whatever) and just adds it at the end (or ignore it totally...especially if it is always +0000)