# I want to parse string to timestamp-with-timezone in python

Tags: python, parsing, timestamp-with-timezone

I try to parse string to time-stamp with timezone format.

here is an example

```
"2016-02-18 16:13:07+09"
```

i want to know parsing this string format to time-stamp format in **python.**

how can i do that?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how can i try this T.T

Comment: Try writing a simple script that parses something much simpler than what you want to parse, using time.strptime, something like "2016-02-18"

Comment: hmm... just that's all? i need more efficient method

Comment: Please include a code example of your trial and error in your question.

Comment: Just that's all. what is this situation, i have to get the timestamp with timezone data from database, then i need insert another database. but when i bring that timestamp from first database, timestamp format is transformed to string format. So i need parse this string type to timestamp with timezone format

Comment: I see, Have you tried to code it yourself before posting this question on SO?

Comment: It is just simple question, this problem doesn't need my code. why i post my code about this problem? i just need a library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how can I turn this format into a unix timestamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402390/in-python-how-can-i-turn-this-format-into-a-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 7):

Is the  UTC offset  format in your string  +09 or +0900 ?

If the offset in your string is 0900 you can use the below .If your UTC offset is only +09 as you mentioned in your question , you can pad the string with 00 and get the below code to work .

**Code:**

```
import datetime  
time="2016-02-18 16:13:07+0900"  
new_time=datetime.datetime.strptime(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")  
print(new_time)  
new_time_python=datetime.datetime.strftime(new_time,"%m-%d-%y")  
print(new_time_python)
```

#### Output

```
2016-02-18 16:13:07+09:00  
02-18-16
```

Answer (score 1):

`dateutil` might be a suitable library for your purposes:

```
from dateutil.parser import parser

p = parser()
d = p.parse('2016-02-18 16:13:07+09'.decode('utf-8'))  # must be unicode string
d
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 18, 16, 13, 7, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 32400))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UTC offset may be specified both as `+HH` and `+HHMM` format then you could use [`str.ljust()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to normalize the input time string. Then you could [use `.strptime()` to parse it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime

time_string = "2016-02-18 16:13:07+09"
dt = datetime.strptime(time_string.ljust(24, "0"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
# ->  datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 18, 16, 13, 7, 
#                       tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 32400)))
```

If your Python version doesn't support `%z`,  see [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101508/4279)

Comment: working on python 3.8 but you have to use a 4 digit offset: (+0900 instead of +09)

Comment: @marcosbdm: the code works as is https://ideone.com/1gHBBd