# Convert datetime since a given date to minutes

Tags: python, datetime, int, python-2.6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python datetime to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp)

Is there a way to convert a `datetime` to `int`, representing the minutes since, for example, January 2012, so that this `int` can be modified, written to a database, compared and so on?
EDIT:
The server I am running this on uses Python 2.6.6

Comment: Please, try `datetime.datetime.strptime` and than `timestamp()` function from 'datetime'.

Answer (score 29):

Subtracting two `datetime.datetime` objects gives you a [`timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), which has a [`.total_seconds()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) (added in Python 2.7). Divide this by 60 and cast to `int()` to get minutes since your reference date:

```
import datetime

january1st = datetime.datetime(2012, 01, 01)
timesince = datetime.datetime.now() - january1st
minutessince = int(timesince.total_seconds() / 60)
```

or in a python shell:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> january1st = datetime.datetime(2012, 01, 01)
>>> timesince = datetime.datetime.now() - january1st
>>> minutessince = int(timesince.total_seconds() / 60)
>>> minutessince
346208
```

For python 2.6 and earlier, you'll have to use the `.days` and `.seconds` attributes to calculate the minutes:

```
minutessince = timesince.days * 1440 + timesince.seconds // 60
```

which gives you an integer as well.

Comment: only 608 minutes from January 1st, doesn't this ring a bell? :) `.seconds` is since midnight, you want `.total_seconds()`

Comment: @Kos: My, are we all stumbling today.. All fixed up now (including spelling the `//` operator correctly, really had too little sleep last night).

Comment: Also, the OP needs an `int`. :-)

Comment: @Kos: yeah, `total_seconds()` is a float, already corrected..

Comment: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'. The server I am running this on is using Python 2.6.6-possibly too old?

Comment: Too old. :) Martijn has suggested to use `t.seconds // 60 + t.days * 24*60` some edits ago, you can fall back to that if your server is outdated.

Comment: @user530476: Yes, I'll update the answer to fit python 2.6 as well (`total_seconds()` was introduced in 2.7).

Answer (score 3):

By substracting datetimes, you can have a timedelta. This timedelta can be divided itself to give you what you want :

```py
(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1)) // datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

(this code is only valid with python3, and that's why everybody should switch to python3 ;-) )

Comment: Nope, you can't divide a timedelta by another timedelta.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: Ah, missed something indeed; the SO syntax highlighting incorrectly marked it as a comment and I am not awake enough to notice things.. Nice trick!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yay, I made the // work !

Comment: Interesting, I wonder which ones of the tags interferes with setting a proper syntax highlighting language here. Normally the `python` tag on the question should be enough to make this work, but if one of the other tags has a *different* language associated with it then the highlighter falls back to auto-detect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep. None of the `language: .*py` worked. The only one was `language-all: lang-py`

Comment: I just noticed the same problem on another post; I suspect that the language flag associated with the `python` tag is actually wrong..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think it's related to tags, I tried with lang-py (so not using tags), and it did not work. It only works with the language-all …

Answer (score 2):

If you want the minutes of the delta between two dates, you can make a `datetime.timedelta` object by subtracting the two dates (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)), and then retrieve the minutes as shown in this question:

[Convert a timedelta to days, hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: Not entirely, the linked question doesn't give you a way to calculate the total minutes in a timedelta. The `.total_seconds()` method wasn't available yet at the time those answers were written, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> then  = datetime.datetime(year=2012, month=1, day=1)
>>> delta=now-then
```

This is a timedelta object representing an interval of time.

```
>>> print delta
240 days, 11:05:25.507000
```

To count the minutes during that interval, use:

```
>>> print delta.total_seconds() / 60
346265.42511666665
```

Comment: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: Update your Python. [total_seconds](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) was introduced in 2.7 (2010).