# Using pytz to convert from a known timezone to local

Tags: python, pytz

I'm receiving a date in a fixed timezone. I need to convert it to the local machine's timezone, but I don't know what that is. How can I do this using pytz (*not* dateutil)? I've found plenty of solutions which use dateutil, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771733/96079), but I can't find a similar function in pytz.

Comment: Unfortunately the reason you can't find a similar function in `pytz` is that it doesn't exist. `pytz` requires you to name the timezone so it can look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert via a (UTC) Unix timestamp:

```
foreign_naive = datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 11, 6, 0, 0)
foreign_timezone = 'US/Eastern'
foreign_dt = pytz.timezone(foreign_timezone).localize(foreign_naive)
timestamp = time.mktime(foreign_dt).astimezone(pytz.utc).timetuple()
local_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

This uses the solution from [Python Create unix timestamp five minutes in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp).

Note that this won't tell you what the local timezone *is*, although you can find out its offset from UTC at that time using:

```
(local_dt - datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)).seconds
```

Comment: Knowing the current offset from UTC won't be useful in any timezone using daylight saving time.

Comment: @MarkRansom that's not a problem; comparing `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` to `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp` gives you the offset at `timestamp`.

Comment: The original question states the local machine's timezone is unknown.

Comment: @MarkRansom right, and you don't need to know the local machine's timezone to use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`.