# How to translate a date string to a timestamp?

Tags: python, django, time

I want to convert a date-field (taken from a PostgreSQL string)

```
"2009-02-13 15:31:30.123000"
```

to a UNIX timestamp like

```
1234567890.123
```

Precision is at the millisecond level. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse datetime string using datetime.datetime.strptime(some_datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').

And then use this answer [Python Create unix timestamp five minutes in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp) to convert datetime.datetime to unix timestamp.

Comment: That's not enough. The milliseconds are discarded during conversion to a `timetuple`.

Comment: You may add datetime_object.microsecond / 1000000.0.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert it to a `datetime` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2009-02-13 15:31:30.123000", 
...                                   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 13, 15, 31, 30, 123000)
```

Then, convert it to a timestamp:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
>>> t
1234535490.0
```

Now, add the microseconds:

```
>>> t += date.microsecond/1000000.0
>>> t
1234535490.123
```

or, if you want to discard anything less than a millisecond:

```
>>> t += int(date.microsecond/1000)/1000.0
```

(`int()` conversion is not necessary in Python 2, but left here for compatibility with Python 3).