# Convert datetime format into seconds

Tags: python, datetime

My date is in the format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` , ie `16/08/2013 09:51:43` . How can I convert the date into python seconds using `total_seconds()` or using any other python function?

Comment: What are "python seconds" do you mean a unix timestamp?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import time
>>> s = "16/08/2013 09:51:43"
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
>>> time.mktime(d.timetuple())
1376632303.0
```

Also see [Python Create unix timestamp five minutes in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp).

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> tt = datetime.datetime( 2013, 8, 15, 6, 0, 0 )
>>> print int(tt.strftime('%s'))
1376535600
```

Answer (score 10):

Seconds since when?

See this code for general second computation:

```
from datetime import datetime
since = datetime( 1970, 8, 15, 6, 0, 0 )
mytime = datetime( 2013, 6, 11, 6, 0, 0 )
diff_seconds = (mytime-since).total_seconds()
```

**UPDATE**: if you need unix timestamp (i.e. seconds since 1970-01-01) you can use the language default value for timestamp of 0 (thanks to comment by J.F. Sebastian):

```
from datetime import datetime
mytime = datetime( 2013, 6, 11, 6, 0, 0 )
diff_seconds = (mytime-datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: if `mytime` is a local time then you could use `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` to get `since` value.