# How can I convert HH:MM:SS string to UNIX epoch time?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a program ([sar command line utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar)) which outputs it's lines with time column. I parse this file with my python script and I would like to convert sar's `02:31:33 PM` into epochs e.g. `1377181906` (current year, month and day with hours, minutes and seconds from abovementioned string). How can this done in a less cumbersome way? I tried to do this by myself, but stuck with time/datetime and herd of their methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: Not quite the dupe, cause I don't have year/day/month. I **can** use `strptime` but it will initialize missing values to 1 january of 1900 year. I can retrieve missing values by myself and append them to the string, but this lies into *cumbersome* category.

Comment: yes, hence the reason I Didn't mark it as dupe/vote to close.  Strptime is the way I would do it (I just set the date/time to now, and then parse much like @alecxe is doing..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

- read the string into datetime using `strptime`
- set year, month, day of the datetime object to current date's year, month and day via `replace`
- convert datetime into unix timestamp via `calendar.timegm`

---

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("02:31:33 PM", "%I:%M:%S %p")
>>> dt_now = datetime.now()
>>> dt = dt.replace(year=dt_now.year, month=dt_now.month, day=dt_now.day)
>>> calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
1377138693
```

Note that in python >= 3.3, you can get the timestamp from a datetime by calling [dt.timestamp()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).

Also see:

- [Python Create unix timestamp five minutes in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 4):

An another way to have epoch time is to use **mktime** from time module and pass time tuple of date, so you can do this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from time import mktime
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("02:31:33 PM", "%H:%M:%S %p")
>>> dt_now = datetime.now()
>>> dt = dt.replace(year=dt_now.year, month=dt_now.month, day=dt_now.day)
>>> int(mktime(dt.timetuple()))
1377131493
```