# converting unix timestamp to local time

Tags: python

I'm attempting to convert `time.time()` to the local time. Reading [python datetime to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp), I understand there's some limitations given that the timestamp is in UTC. However, in lieu of just doing:

```
time.time() - (6*60*60)
```

Is there a way to convert from UTC to CST and get the CST Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to get the current local time, and then [convert that to a UNIX timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775864/python-datetime-to-unix-timestamp):

```
import datetime
import calendar

now = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())
```

Or on Python 3.3+:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
```